# JavaScript emulate window being in focus

Tags: javascript

For a project I need to be able to pull data from a minimized tab that displays the Instagram website. Everything works except for the "minimized" part. As soon as the window is minimized, and I refresh the page, there is no image data coming in. This is why I think it is necessary to "trick" the website into thinking that it's onscreen in order for it to load data.

Steps to reproduce:

1. open https://www.instagram.com/
2. right-click > Inspect (Developer Tools, please undock for windowed mode)
3. confirm that the `_4rbun` elements contain a `srcset` with the images
4. minimize Instagram tab
5. in the console, type `location.reload()` to reload the page
6. in dev tools, confirm that there are 0 or 1 `_4rbun` elements which however don't contain a picture
7. open the minimized tab
8. confirm that there are numerous `_4rbun` elements which all contain links in their `srcset`s

Similar behavior can be found in the /explore path except that this, on the contrary, at least contains links to the pages displaying the image (but still no direct link to the .jpg)

Is there anything i can do about this? Other websites use things like Store.js to keep track of their data but I couldn't find anything like this in the website's `window` object so either going the "hacky" focus way or the much cleaner "Store"-kind of way would be fine.

What I've tried was to override `hasFocus` like the following `document.hasFocus = function(){return true};` which does keep the value on `true` but doesn't seem to affect the website's behavior at all. And I have tried finding an object carrying links etc. but this has been unsuccessful so far, too.

Comment: Could it be the browser not loading the images when the tab does not have focus?

Comment: Is the srcset being added by JS? Add a chrome element breakpoint and reload the page and see what JS is adding the srcset and why

Comment: @Charlie - [srcset](https://caniuse.com/#search=srcset) is supported by nearly all modern browsers, without the need for JavaScript.

Comment: @Matthieu I don't think this is the issue as it doesn't even prepare more than one `_4rbun` element. 

@Charlie there is a function called `componentDidUpdate` which gets called when setting the srcset but I really am unable to track this down properly

Comment: I've just used an AJAX debugger and when I open the window it does send get requests for all the pictures' URL's - but where does it get the URL's from? I can't find the URL's in any incoming packet, only in the tab's GET requests but not at any time prior to that

Comment: @fubar sure; but as OP states, the attribute isn't set when the window is minimized.
Riccccck It might be built at runtime. Chrome's network log will show what initiated the request. Try setting a breakpoint and walking down the callstack until you find out where.